# Use picker view selected row text

Tags: ios, swift, text, uipickerview

I want to get the string value for a selected row in a UIPickerView simply, with a call like :

```
let myString = getString(from: myPickerView, inComponent: 0)
```

I've tried to extend the UIPickerViewDelegate class like that :

```
extension UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func getString(from pickerView: UIPickerView, inComponent component: Int) -> String {
        return pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component), forComponent: component)
    }

}
```

But I getting an error:

> " Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIPickerView' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I replace :

```
func getString(from pickerView: UIPickerView, inComponent component: Int) -> String {
   return pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component), forComponent: component)
}
```

by :

```
func getString(from picker: UIPickerView, inComponent selectedComponent: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerView!(picker, titleForRow: picker.selectedRow(inComponent: selectedComponent), forComponent: selectedComponent)
}
```